# C - Get Process ID of signalling process

Tags: c, signals, pid

So this is the problem im having right now, I've created 2 different programs (1 will be managing the other, while the other will be executed multiple times). The programs will be communicating back and forth via signals. My question is, is it possible (and how) to get the process id of the program sending the signal.
My programs use signal() to catch signals and kill() to send them.

Answer (score 3):

Although signal() is in standard C library, this function is not portable, its behavior depending on the system. Better use sigaction() which is POSIX.1.

Here is an example of how to use sigaction with a handler void h(int sig) :

```
int mysignal (int sig, void (*h)(int), int options)
{
    int r;
    struct sigaction s;
    s.sa_handler = h;
    sigemptyset (&s.sa_mask);
    s.sa_flags = options;
    r = sigaction (sig, &s, NULL);
    if (r < 0) perror (__func__);
    return r;
}
```

options are described in man sigaction. A good choice is `options=SA_RESTART`.

To know the PID of the process which sent a signal, set `options=SA_SIGINFO`, and use a `sa_sigaction` callback instead of `sa_handler`; it will receive a `siginfo_t` struct, having a `si_pid` field. You can associate a data to the signal using `sigqueue`.

Generally speaking, using signals is a bad idea to communicate in a safe manner (when n signals are sent, only the first will have a chance to be delivered; there is no hook to associate other datas; the available user signals are only two). Better use pipes, named pipes or sockets.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `signal()`, it's obsolete. If you have it, use [`sigaction()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) instead, it provides an interface to get the sender's process ID.

Comment: It won't catch sigkill and sigstop. For example, if you press ctrl+c from 2nd process, it won't be caught by sigaction().

Comment: yah thats fine, how do I catch it with sigaction()?

Comment: @Chris: For a `sigaction()` example along with som refreshment on signal handling, take a look at [this article](http://lazarenko.me/2013/01/15/how-not-to-write-a-signal-handler/) that that I wrote some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

To get the process id of the process that is sending the signal you need to include in your options SA_SIGINFO.  If you do so the interface to the sigaction is slightly different.  Here is an example of the proper handler to use and how to set itup.  (I include SA_RESTART as an option just because it is generally a good idea, but it is not necessary)

```
// example of a handler which checks the signalling pid
void handler(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* vp) { 
  if (info->si_pid != getpid()) {
    // not from me (or my call to alarm)
    return;
  }
  // from me.  let me know alarm when off
  alarmWentOff = 1;
}
```

Here is my general code for setting up a handler:

```
typedef void InfoHandler(int, siginfo_t *, void *);

InfoHandler*
SignalWithInfo(int signum, InfoHandler* handler)
{
  struct sigaction action, old_action;

  memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
  action.sa_sigaction = handler;  
  sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask); /* block sigs of type being handled */
  action.sa_flags = SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO; /* restart syscalls if possible */

  if (sigaction(signum, &action, &old_action) < 0)
perror("Signal error");
  return (old_action.sa_sigaction);
}
```

and finally, for this particular case:

```
SignalWithInfo(SIGALRM, handler);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's changed now. The signal information shows not 1 pid, but easy digital number. That accords to the killall process. May be, it's possible, to enumerate the /proc/ directories, when you find the /proc/DIGIT, open the /proc/DIGIT/comm, read and close it. May be, acueried name will be "shutdown" or "reboot"